# pdo prepared statement with changing variable list

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Setting up a search that can have multiple optional filters.

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM table 
        WHERE title = :title 
        AND filter1 = :filter1 
        AND filter2 = :filter2 
        AND filter3 = :filter3";
$query = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(
           array(
             ':title' => $title, 
             ':filter1' => $filter1,
             ':filter2' => $filter2, 
             ':filter3' => $filter3
           )
        );
```

This issue is sometime the filter variables will be empty.  If the filter is empty then any value should work.  I have tried setting the empty filters to a wildcard (%) but that doesn't seem to work.

```
if(empty($filter1)) $filter1 = '%';
```

Comment: In this case a SQL QueryBuilder could be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to conditionally add them to your SQL and to your SQLDATA in the execute().

```
$filters = array(
  ':filter1': $filter1, 
  ':filter2': $filter2, 
  ':filter3': $filter3
);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE title = :title";
$sqldata = array(
  ':title' => $title
);
foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
  $sql .= " AND $key=$value";
  $sqldata[$key] => $value;
}
$query = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($sqldata);
```